# My puppy fell and hit himself, and now he vomited. Is he ok?

Tags: dogs, health

I took my puppy for a walk, and while I was playing with him He fell from my arms and hit himself. I checked him by feeling him little by little and he seemed OK. He did not complain and he even waged his tail.

Now I just took a look at him and saw that he had vomited.

What should I do?

Comment: The condition you describe could be indicative of an urgent or emergency health issue, please contact your vet for direction on how soon your pet needs to be seen. If someone knowledgeable in first aid is available, they may be able to write an answer, but you should not wait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More details would help. Did he hit his head? If not, what part of his body did he hit, and on what?

The proximity you describe is worrisome. Without more details it's hard to recommend anything except that you call your vet.

Head injury commonly causes vomiting. Without external signs of trauma, eg lacerations or swelling on his head, a single episode of vomiting without *any other symptoms* is probably ok, seeing as he didn't lose consciousness at the time. Symptoms of concern would include being dazed, wobbly, or disoriented. Seizure, decreased level of consciousness, bleeding from the ears or nose, and not holding his head correctly are very serious symptoms requiring immediate treatment.

If he didn't strike his head, look for trouble concerning what he did hit. Though not likely to be associated with vomiting, he could have bruised some ribs (watch for breathing abnormalities) or hurt some other part of his body. Run your hands over his entire body; if he reacts with pain, limps, or has other symptoms, call your vet.

<sub>[Types of Head Injuries in Dogs](http://pets.webmd.com/dogs/types-dog-head-injuries)</sub>
<sub>[Trauma to the Chest in Dogs](http://www.petplace.com/article/dogs/diseases-conditions-of-dogs/emergency-trauma-urgent-care/trauma-to-the-chest-in-dogs)</sub>

Comment: Hi Medica,

Thank you for you great response.

It happened so quickly that I barely had time to react, but I think that he may have hit his snout. Now I did just as you suggested and a ran my finders all over the puppy to check for discomfort, but I couldn't find any.

This morning I took him to the vet and he did a number of tests on him. He ran his fingers all over him to check for discomfort, he checked all of his limbs and joints, he checked for coordination and reflexes as well.

The verdict is that this was more of a scare than anything else. However I'll keep monitoring him.

Thank you